# HTML embedded with applets or flash in phonegap

Tags: android, html, flash, cordova, applet

I have successfully converted websites using just plain html, css or js into apk files. But html with embedded applets or flash files are not working! I tried with phonegap on android.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any exceptions or anything that could help us to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems applets are not supported by mobile browsers.
For flash, the following link helped:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/s3xZ8qxTL-M